# WxWidgets clear static bitmap control

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxStaticBitmap in the UI, and set it to an image.  Later I want to clear it back to no image at all.

How do I do that?

Comment: use `wxNULLBitmap`.

Comment: see https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/interface_2wx_2bitmap_8h.html#a2947690e84b8fdb2e37b79a4af8f8a21

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, do something like this:

```
myStaticBitmap->SetBitmap(wxNullBitmap);
```

Be careful : it will change the layout of your UI as the wxStaticBitmap control client area min size will be set to (0, 0).